# Getting weired "No results were returned by the query." error when executing a Postgres native SELECT query inside String boot application

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the following error when trying to execute a native Select query.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.TypeInfoCache.getPGArrayElement(TypeInfoCache.java:657) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]

The query code is as follows:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT" +
            " rg.id," +
            " data_set," +
            " group_name," +
            " g.name AS guide_name," +
            " type  ," +
            " guide_id_unnest as guide_id " +
            " FROM" +
            " nmi.repeating_group rg," +
            " unnest(rg.guide_id) AS guide_id_unnest " +
            " JOIN" +
            " nmi.guide g" +
            " ON g.id = guide_id_unnest", nativeQuery = true)
    Iterable<RepeatingGroup> findAllRepeatingGroups();
```

I can successfully execute this query in pgAdmin.

When I am debugging it is throwing this error at this location: `TypeInfoCache`
inside `package org.postgresql.jdbc;`

Can you please tell me if I am doing something incorrect?